# No object file from cmake

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake, object-files

I have a C++ program I'm trying to make with CMake. The cmake part seems to go well, I get the following messages when I run cmake .. in the build directory:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/program/build
```

But when I run make -i, I get the following errors:

```
Scanning dependencies of target project
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/project.dir/project.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable project
c++: error: CMakeFiles/project.dir/project.cpp.o: No such file or directory
[100%] Built target project
```

So am I missing a step somewhere? Do I have to manually create the object file in CMakeLists.txt somewhere? Thanks!

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (Project)

#include header files
include_directories(~/project)
set(SOURCES project.cpp ~/project/pmddatadescription.h ~/project/pmdsdk2.h ~/project/pmdsdk2common.h ~/project/stdafx.h)

# PCL
find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

# VTK
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

# add the executable
add_executable(project project.cpp ${SOURCES})
#link installed libraries
target_link_libraries (project ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(project ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
#link .so libraries
target_link_libraries(project ~/project/libpmdaccess2.so)
```

Comment: Only specify `.cpp` files for `SOURCES`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Including .h files should be fine (indeed, I do it all the time so they show up in the IDE). I don't think this is the cause of the issue, but he does double-declare project.cpp. You should also have only one target-link-libraries statement.

Comment: You also have project.cpp included twice in your executable: once in the variable SOURCES, and once listed by hand.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I also didn't think this would be the cause of the issue. I just mentioned this as a side note.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Here's my updated CMakeLists.txt. I still get the same error. http://pastebin.com/Mv3By1q3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, the matter is in the `-i` option?

```
-i, --ignore-errors
    Ignore all errors in commands executed to remake files.
```

Comment: I do this to ignore 3 errors that come up in compiling program.cpp. Don't think that's the problem. It won't even get to that step if I don't include -i.

Comment: @user3738294 fix error in program.cpp, most probably it skips building project.o due to error in building program.cpp. And exactly it would not get to that step, because you must fix compilation errors before project can me linked succesfully.

Comment: +1 I do believe you are right, I never saw anyone use this command before. But yeah, if there is an error in project.cpp, how on earth do you expect it to produce a project.o?

Comment: Okay, I'll try to fix this then. When I was using a Makefile before, it was just a warning so the code compiled fine. But now with CMake, it seems to have escalated to an error.

Comment: CMake is just a new layer of abstraction above the GNU Make (in your case). Every warning is worth paying attention to it.

Comment: Here's the error I'm getting: 728:49: error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive] and here's that line:
    msg << acos(dot_product(&pcl::PointXYZ(0,0,1), &pcl::PointXYZ(coeffs_vec[0]->values[0],coeffs_vec[0]->values[1],coeffs_vec[0]->values[2]))) * 180.0 / 3.14159265 << "degrees";

Comment: Is the problem with &pcl? When I remove the &, this is the error I get: error: cannot convert ‘pcl::PointXYZ’ to ‘PointType* {aka pcl::PointXYZ*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘float dot_product(PointType*, PointType*)’

Comment: You may create two more variables to store these arguments and then pass their addresses to the `dot_product` function.

Comment: Okay, great. Could I say something like boost::tuples::tuple zlocation = pcl::PointXYZ(0,0,1); or pcl::PointXYZ zlocation = pcl::PointXYZ(0,0,1);? Both of those give me error codes. What would the correct Syntax be?

Comment: `pcl::PointXYZ zlocation(0,0,1);`

Comment: I believe, you have to read some introductory material about the C++ syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I do. I've been going over this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace seems to be helping. Awesome, thanks. This is what the next line looks like: msg << acos(dot_product(&zlocation, &pcl::PointXYZ(coeffs_vec[0]->values[0],coeffs_vec[0]->values[1],coeffs_vec[0]->values[2]))) * 180.0 / 3.14159265 << "degrees"; It's giving me the error that on this line,  ‘zlocation’ was not declared in this scope. But I thought I declared it on the line before?

Comment: I don't see the `zlocation`'s definition. And, again, your second argument is a temporary.

Comment: Here is the section, a bit easier to see. http://pastebin.com/mPZr6d5y Would line 1 not be defining zlocation? Of the type pcl::PointXYZ, or tuple? And yes, I'll do the same thing for the second one once I figure out how to fix this case.

Comment: I don't see error in this listing. Probably, there are some errors/warnings in the previous lines?

Comment: The error (in context) is: project.cpp:2:30: error: ‘zlocation’ was not declared in this scope. I made sure that the spelling of each zlocation was the same.

Comment: Strange, when I fixed the second one, I got no errors. http://pastebin.com/2UikcBk9 The only error now is: project.cpp:3:30: error: ‘zlocation’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Okay, now the error went away when I added brackets to the if statement. Compiled fine on Windows without them. I fixed the third occurrence and now it works! Thanks so much.